# Синтаксис фразы "о 1000 долларов убытков"

Tags: синтаксис, падежи, предлоги, синтаксический-разбор

Помогите разобраться с синтаксисом фразы:

> о 1000 долларов убытков

Ведь после предлога *о* может идти только *предложный падеж*. А где в этой фразе предложный падеж?

> И цифра 1000 сама по себе ничего не значит. Однако если речь идет о
>   1000 долларов убытков, которые малое предприятие несет каждый месяц,
>   то любой потенциальный инвестор обязательно спросит: «Почему?» И
>   покров тайны начнет рассеиваться.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Слова тысяча, миллион, миллиард, как и существительные, всегда управляют формой родительного падежа зависимого существительного, независимо от собственного падежа.

Ср.: тысяча рублей, нет тысячи рублей, с тысячей рублей, о тысяче рублей.

Однако если эти слова включены в состав составных числительных, то там действуют общие правила сочетаемости числительных с существительными.
Нет тысячи пяти рублей, к тысяче пяти рублям, с тысячей пятью рублями, о тысяче пяти рублях.

Answer (score 3):

В предложном падеже здесь числительное: "**о тысяче**" (склоняется как существительное первого склонения). Несмотря на числовой способ записи, читается оно именно так. При желании здесь можно без изменения общего смысла переориентировать предложный падеж на другие слова: "**об убытках** в размере 1000 долларов" или "**о долларах** убытков, в количестве тысячи".

Answer (score 2):

Синтаксис нормальный: тысяча (И.п.) долларов убытков, о тысяче (П.п) долларов убытков.  Здесь "тысяча" - грамматическое существительное с числовым значением, управляет Р.п. существительного "долларов".

Похожий пример: МВФ пообещал банкам два триллиона долларов убытков. Речь идет о двух миллионах долларов убытков.